# how to stop program while alertDialog open?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want stop main thread, while alertDialog is open, and wait user's choice for continue the program (depending on the button pressed buttons (positive or negative)). When trying to stop thread after. show (); dialog is not draw; if hang listener's onDestract onClose it works, but the code is horrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't stop "main" thread, since it's gui thread - your alertDialog will become irresponsive. You need to use callback to perform desired operations.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to stop main thread? Is this some game?
You must use many thread, and never block main thread. For example, thread for logic, thread for draw. 
If you need to stop drawing, simple set your noDraw=true property:)
Like this:

```
SomeDrawer extends View {
   @override
   public void onDraw(...){
      if(noDraw) return;
      redrawMyGame(...);
   }
}
```